# Why is my Javascript for loop concatenating numbers rather than adding?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, math, concatenation, addition

I'm trying to write a little snippet where prompts ask the user for 5 numbers and computes the total of the numbers.

So far I have this:

```
var counter, number, total;

for(counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++) {
  number = parseFloat(prompt("Enter a number:"));
  total += number;
}

document.write("The total is " + total + ".");
```

However the 'total' returns " " for example, rather than a sum of 15.

How do I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *where it prompts

Comment: Add this `total = 0`.

Comment: Initialize `total` to zero.

Comment: Worked, thank you!

Comment: _However the 'total' returns "12345" for example_ - This is probably when you say `total = ""` and not the current code in the question. The code in the question prints `The total is NaN.`

Comment: That was the result before I added in parseFLoat(), apologies. You're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should initialize your `total` var to 0:

```js
var counter, number, total = 0;

for(counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++) {
  number = parseFloat(prompt("Enter a number:"));
  total += number;
}

document.write("The total is " + total + ".");
```

Comment: `number` is useless: You could write: `total += parseFloat(prompt("Enter a number:"));`

Comment: agree @F.Hauri but I only copied his code and fixed his main problem. code optimization should be his thing

Answer (score 2):

You have to set total to 0, like this:

```
var counter, number, total = 0;

for(counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++) {
  number = parseFloat(prompt("Enter a number:"));
  total += number;
}

document.write("The total is " + total + ".");
```

Comment: What mean *"& co"*?  First line dont set any other variable than `total` to `0`! 3 variables are *declared*, but only one is *initialised*.